# Why does this nextflow script finish after running one sample?

Tags: nextflow

I have 36 samples in total in the bam_files folder, with the name like this 20230306_CH_EP_C01.md.bam

I expect the code to output all the 36 samples, one by one. But the run stopped after only running one sample.
I have searched online, but did not find a solution.
I am using nextflow version 2.

```
bam_chl = Channel
     .fromPath("bam_files/*.md.bam")
     .map{ item -> tuple(item.baseName.substring(0, 18), item) }
     

     
ref_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/hg38.fa")
ref_index_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/hg38.fa.fai")
amplicon_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/tp53_amplicon.hg38.interval_list")
target_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/TP53.hg38.interval_list")
     


process get_pcr_metric {

  publishDir path: 'pcr_metric', pattern: '*.csv'
  
  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), path(bam)
  path(ref)
  path(ref_index)
  path(amplicon)
  path(target)

  output:
  path("*.pcr_metrics.csv")

  """
  java -jar /picard.jar CollectTargetedPcrMetrics \
       I=$bam \
   O=${pair_id}_pcr_metrics.txt \
       R=$ref \
   AMPLICON_INTERVALS=$amplicon \
       TARGET_INTERVALS=$target
       
  sed -n -e 7p -e 8p ${pair_id}_pcr_metrics.txt |  sed 's/\t/,/g'   > ${pair_id}.pcr_metrics.csv
  
  

  """


}


workflow {

get_pcr_metric(bam_chl, ref_chl,ref_index_chl, amplicon_chl, target_chl)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the [`fromPath`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#frompath) factory method produces a [queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel), but you don't want all of your input channels to be queue channels. Most of the time, what you want is one queue channel and one or more [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) channels when you require [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels).

You *could* use the [`value`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value) factory method to create the value channels, but a simpler way is to just pass in some file objects. The latter works because a value channel is implicitly created by a process when it is invoked with a simple value<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-type-value)</sup>. For example:

```
params.ref_fasta = "./sequences/hg38.fa"
params.amplicon_intervals = "./sequences/tp53_amplicon_intervals.hg38.interval_list"
params.target_intervals = "./sequences/TP53.hg38.interval_list"

params.bam_files = "./bam_files/*.md.bam"
params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process get_pcr_metric {

    publishDir path: "${params.outdir}/pcr_metric", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(bam_file)
    path ref_fasta
    path amplicon_intervals
    path target_intervals

    output:
    path "${pair_id}_pcr_metrics.txt"

    """
    picard CollectTargetedPcrMetrics \\
         I="${bam_file}" \\
         O="${pair_id}_pcr_metrics.txt" \\
         R="${ref_fasta}" \\
         AMPLICON_INTERVALS="${amplicon_intervals}" \\
         TARGET_INTERVALS="${target_intervals}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    ref_fasta = file( params.ref_fasta )
    amplicon_intervals = file( params.amplicon_intervals )
    target_intervals = file( params.target_intervals )

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.bam_files )
        .map { tuple( it.getBaseName(2), it ) }
        .set { bam_files }

    get_pcr_metric( bam_files, ref_fasta, amplicon_intervals, target_intervals )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code can be made to work on *all* samples by changing the interface of the process and using the `combine` operator:

```
ref_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/hg38.fa")
ref_index_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/hg38.fa.fai")
amplicon_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/tp53_amplicon.hg38.interval_list")
target_chl = Channel
      .fromPath("sequences/TP53.hg38.interval_list")

bam_chl = Channel
     .fromPath("bam_files/*.md.bam")
     .map{ item -> tuple(item.baseName.substring(0, 18), item) }
     .combine(ref_chl)
     .combine(ref_index_chl)
     .combine(amplicon_chl)
     .combine(target_chl)

process get_pcr_metric {

  publishDir path: 'pcr_metric', pattern: '*.csv'
  
  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), path(bam), path(ref), path(ref_index), path(amplicon), path(target)

  output:
  path("*.pcr_metrics.csv")

  """
  java -jar /picard.jar CollectTargetedPcrMetrics \
       I=$bam \
   O=${pair_id}_pcr_metrics.txt \
       R=$ref \
   AMPLICON_INTERVALS=$amplicon \
       TARGET_INTERVALS=$target
       
  sed -n -e 7p -e 8p ${pair_id}_pcr_metrics.txt |  sed 's/\t/,/g'   > ${pair_id}.pcr_metrics.csv
  """
}

workflow {
  get_pcr_metric(bam_chl)
}
```

The `combine` operator as the name implies generates all combinations. The different file objects are then in one tuple.

Since only one `Channel` is passed to the process, it's now also possible to rewrite the workflow code as follows:

```
workflow {

  refs = [
    "sequences/hg38.fa",
    "sequences/hg38.fa.fai",
    "sequences/tp53_amplicon.hg38.interval_list",
    "sequences/TP53.hg38.interval_list"
  ]

  ref_chl = Channel.from(refs)
   | map{ pointer -> file(pointer) }
   | collect

  Channel.fromPath("bam_files/*.md.bam")
   | map{ item -> tuple(item.baseName.substring(0, 18), item) }
   | combine( ref_chl )
   | get_pcr_metric

}
```

Comment: You do not need the `combine` operator here: In general, [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels) should be used to process _combinations_ of different inputs, using the `each` qualifier or value channels.